# I receive Error Protocol(Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed when try to validate selectors on the page

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

I develop a test on the puppeteer-jest framework, and receive an error with Runtime.callFunctionOn. Problem with functions isOverviewTpabPresent, isPeopleTabPresent, isSocialTabPresent, isFinanceTabPresent

I see some solution for that in the stack or on the official GitHub repository, but that not help.

Test:

```
    it(`${testcase.C673055.id} - ${testcase.C673055.name}`, async C673055 => {
        await goto(homePage, HOME_PAGE_RELATIVE_PATH);
        await listPage.clickAdvancedSearch(homePage);
        await takeScreenshot(homePage, `advancedSearchPage`);
        await advancedSearchPage.clickFinanceCategory(homePage);
        await takeScreenshot(homePage, `Finance_click`);
        await advancedSearchPage.clickFilter(homePage, `Company Size & Offices`);
        await takeScreenshot(homePage, `Open_CompanyFilter`);
        await advancedSearchPage.setHeadcount1k(homePage);
        await takeScreenshot(homePage, `Take_Filter_to_1K`);
        await advancedSearchPage.clickFilter(homePage, `Keywords`);
        await takeScreenshot(homePage, `Open_Keywords`);
        await advancedSearchPage.fillKeywords(homePage, companies.creditKarmaInc.name);
        await takeScreenshot(homePage, `Fill_Keywords`);
        await advancedSearchPage.clickViewCompanies(homePage);
        await companyPage.isOverviewTpabPresent(homePage);
        await takeScreenshot(homePage, `companyPage`);
        await companyPage.isPeopleTabPresent(homePage);
        await companyPage.isSocialTabPresent(homePage);
        await companyPage.isFinanceTabPresent(homePage);
        await homePage.close();
```

Function isOverviewPresent:

```
async function isOverviewTabPresent(page) {
    validatePageSelectorAvailable(page, companyPageLocators.overviewTab.locator);
}
```

Function validation:

```
async function validatePageSelectorAvailable(page, selector) {
    return expect(page).toMatchElement(selector);
}
```

I expected not to receive that error and test passed result should be.

Comment: What's the error? An error on `Runtime.callFunctionOn` tends to be an error with the javascript being sent to chromium.

Comment: @hardkoded yes, error is: `Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed`

Comment: What's the evaluate you are sending that it's failing?

Comment: I want to check is an element is displayed using the function: `expect(page).toMatchElement(selector);`

Comment: Is that a typo? "isOverviewTpabPresent" Notice the Tpab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for promise to finish. Either return the promise or add await before validatePageSelectorAvailable function call.

```
async function isOverviewTabPresent(page) {
    await validatePageSelectorAvailable(page, companyPageLocators.overviewTab.locator);
}
```

Check if rest of your code has such promises that are not awaited. **Target closed** shows when you close the browser/tab mostly because of not waiting for promise to finish.

Comment: Thank you, it is worked. I return Promises and that is work without error.